# SQLAlchemy: link two already existing objects in a database

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for method to link two already existing objects in a database.

Let's say I have a file and a fact in the database which aren't linked already. How do I get the ids in the association table?

```
facts_info = Table(
"facts_info",
Base.metadata,
sqlColumn("fact_id", Integer, ForeignKey("fact.id"), primary_key=True),
sqlColumn("info_id", Integer, ForeignKey("info.id"), primary_key=True),


class Facts(Base):
   __tablename__ = "facts"

   id = sqlColumn(Integer, primary_key=True)
   fact = sqlColumn(String(500), nullable=False, unique=True)
   created_at = sqlColumn(DateTime)
   updated_at = sqlColumn(DateTime)

   # Relationships
   info = relationship("Info", secondary=sachverhalt_info, 
   back_populates="fact")


class Info(Base):
   __tablename__ = "info"

   id = sqlColumn(Integer, primary_key=True)
   filename = sqlColumn(String(50))
   format = sqlColumn(String(10))

   # Relationships
   fact = relationship("Facts", secondary=facts_info; 
   back_populates="info")
```

I already tried the following:

```
old_fact = session.execute(select(Facts).where(Facts.fact == "foo").scalars().first()
old_info = session.execute(select(Infos).where(Infos.filename == "example.txt").scalars().first()
```

As a result of the query I get the correct instances:

```
Facts(id=1, fact="foo", created_at="2021-08-02", updated_at=Null)
Infos(id=1, filename="example.txt", format="txt")
```

If these instances already exist in the database

```
old_fact.info.append(old_info)
session.commit()
```

doesn't put the ids into the association table.

If I create a new instance und append it to the other one, the association table gets filled correctly.

```
new_fact = Facts(id=2, fact="bar", created_at="2021-08-02", updated_at=Null)
new_info = Infos(id=2, filename="test.txt", format="txt")

session.add(new_fact)
new_fact.info.append(new_info)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Retrieve the "file" (Info) and the "Fact" that you want to associate. Append one of them to the relationship of the other, e.g., `my_fact.info.append(my_info)`, and then call `session.commit()`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. If I do so nothing happens. This only works if these objects don't already exist in the database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are trying to retrieve the existing objects from the database.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/Ze8szgH7) works for me.

Comment: I actually typed .scalars() instead of scalar().  I don't really know what's the issue, but it works now. Thank your for your help!